# No Launcher or application access after updating

Tags: package-management, launcher, unity-dash, panel

I have just run a full Ubuntu software update on my Lenovo Thinkpad 2013. I now have no Launcher and no way of accessing applications, only an empty desktop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to a shell in character mode by issuing Alt-Ctl-F2, log in and issue this command `unity`

Answer (score 0):

When you sign on you need to select the same Desktop you upgraded from. If you select the wrong one you can end up with a purplish screen and a movable mouse cursor.

To select the right Desktop click the gear icon next to the <kbd>Sign In</kbd> button on the login screen. This drop down menu will appear:

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 Five Desktops.jpg]